# Decrypt files with OpenSSL via Batch File

Tags: batch-file, encryption, openssl

i need to decrypt several files each day with OpenSSL.

When i'm using: `C:\OpenSSL-Win32\bin\openssl enc -d -aes-256-cbc -nopad -K my_encryption_key -iv 0 -in "P:\Testing\encrypted\013_1983987_20210116.xml" -out "P:\Testing\decrypted\013_1983987_20210116.xml"` it works fine. Thus I have to repeat this step for every single file.

I tried a simple batch with following code:

```
for /f %%a IN ('dir /b "P:\Testing\encrypted\*"') DO (
C:\OpenSSL-Win32\bin\openssl enc -d -aes-256-cbc -nopad -K my_encryption_key -iv 0 -in "P:\Testing\encrypted\%%a" -out "P:\Testing\decrypted\%%a" )
pause
```

It generates files in my decrypted directory but it does not decrypt those files.

I'm a real newbie to this so please be nice :-)

Really big thanks in advance!

Greetings
k0nz3pt

Comment: If it's generating all of your files in the target directory, then the for loop is working as intended, and your issue must be with the `openssl` command you are running. If it is not generating all of the files, then I would advise you to change to this syntax, `FOR /F "EOL=? Delims=" %%a In ('DIR /B /A:-D "P:\Testing\encrypted"') DO …`.

Comment: Thank you for your help. It's generating new files in the target directory but they are still encrypted. It doesn't make sense to me that the simple command works but not the loop sequence. I already copied the code out of the DOS window and run it again. If i do so it works again. That in mind the `openssl` code should be correct.

Comment: The for loop does nothing except for propagate the openssl line with the iterated filenames. There is no other magic happening there, so the issue must be that either openssl cannot decrypt your files, or that line is incorrect. If you had just one file inside `P:\Testing\encrypted`, named `013_1983987_20210116.xml`, the openssl command would expand `-in` to `"P:\Testing\encrypted\013_1983987_20210116.xml'`, and `-out` to `"P:\Testing\decrypted\013_1983987_20210116.xml'`. Those exactly match the example you say works without issue. If that is the case, your issue cannot be reproduced.

Comment: Yeah, that's why i'm so confused. the `for` loop does its job as it should. The result is correct and I can copy the lines and run them again and my files get decrypted. I try to make a video later to show you.

Comment: I can not reproduce this, what you did works fine for me when using `-K 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 -iv 00000000000000000000000000000000`. I use the full length key and iv strings here to avoid _hex string is too short_ warnings. What version of OpenSSL are you using? By the way, it seems a little weird to use `-nopad` because that requires your data to be an exact multiple of the block size, which may not be the case with XML as input.